# Thumbnails - Create local device or download from server

Tags: c#, android, ios, objective-c, image

My question is performance related. I'm developing a native photo gallery mobile devices that downloads images form a server. I'm pondering weather I should store a thumbnail of each image on the server and download it for each image, or create a thumbnail for each image on the local device.
Which is the better choice?

Comment: I think I can answer this now that I've asked it lol. I Think it's best to create a thumbnail on the server so that the app would download all the small thumbnails first for quick viewing. then download the large ones if the user selects them. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be estimated with the traffic your site is likely to receive and the number of images that can be on the site/server, if you believe that the site will have a lot of traffic on lot of different images, then creating thumbnails is better as it will not eat up the resources.

I run a site which has more than 25,000 images and I have created thumbnails for each, as there are more than 15-20 requests per minute. That will amount to a lot of processing otherwise.

Comment: That makes sense. I think I'll end up creating thumbnail for each image when the images are uploaded to the server. Because each user most likely won't be viewing every picture.